# Flip rotated text on CGContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgcontext

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbzar.png

I want to get text on 90-270 degrees (text "Aroma 7" to "Aroma 17"), rotated 180 degrees.

My code:

```
 for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Aroma %d", i];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, radius, radius);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, i * 15 * M_PI/180.0);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, - (radius), -(radius));

    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]
                     constrainedToSize:rect.size
                         lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakByWordWrapping)];

    [str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(((radius * 2) - 10) - size.width, radius) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];


    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should produce the wanted output:

```
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Aroma %d", i];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, radius, radius);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, i * 15 * M_PI/180.0);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]
                  constrainedToSize:rect.size
                      lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakByWordWrapping)];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, radius-10-size.width/2, size.height/2); // (1)
    if (i >= 7 && i <= 17)
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI); // (2)
    [str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-size.width/2, -size.height/2) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The idea is to move the origin of the coordinate system to the center of the rectangle where the text is to be drawn (see `(1)`). Then you can simply rotate the text by 180 degrees (see `(2)`).

This is the output of my test program:

[image]

Comment: This is really brilliant. I would have up-voted multiple times if I could.